# Slow USB Speed Likely due to uhci driver being loaded

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

It seems all my USB devices are being throttled back to USB1.1 (Full-Speed), and the best I can tell it's due to the kernel loading the uhci driver for the instead of ehci. I've tried every iteration of the USB settings in the BIOS to try and get any device to load with ehci, but they always come with uhci.

[Here's the dmesg output during boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFSMI.png)

[And here is when I attach a USB2.0 thumbdrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWGJE.png)

This is on an older Zotac board, but it does have 6 USB 2.0 ports, so I'm trying to figure out why they won't use the ehci (High-speed) driver.

Any help would be appreciated, as this is further into linux troubleshooting I've ever had to go before.

System: ZOTAC ZBOX HD-ID11
Running: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve it. Buried in the BOIS under the Southbridge settings the USB2.0 controller was disabled. D'oh!